# link static php files to nav header on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've in `header.php` list items containing:

```
 home
 about us
 support
 contact us
```

I need to link them with php files in my theme in wordpress:
 `index.php`

```
 about-us.php

 contact-us.php

 support.php
```

I tried for home this code:

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
```

and worked with home page only.. so what about the other files

I need something similar to

> about us

because any page have included different header, footer and other

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you try this code

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(page-id); ?>">about us</a></li>
```

Comment: no its not, the pages its not created from wordpress pages admin screen,
I need to link about-us.php in the list item for it